# Using Angular CLI and unable to use relative image paths in CSS files

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Have setup an angular app using the angular CLI and have created a component that has an image in the components directory.

For example:

```
app/
---/common-components
------/header
---------/header.component.ts
---------/header.component.css
---------/images
--------------/image.png
```

Within the CSS file I am using the following style:

```
.image {
    background-url: url('images/image.png');
}
```

When I run the application it gives me a 304 Not Modified and the image does not show up int he preview.  If I use an absolute path '/src/app/common-components/header/images' the file loads properly.  However, this is not ideal since I would like the component to be self sufficient.

The response that is given is:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4201/images/test-image.jpeg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4201
```

With a blank preview

Comment: Did you trying loading the image like url('./images/image.png')?

Comment: @nicowernli yep, I tried that as well and it did not work.

Comment: The css property is `background-image` not `background-url`

Comment: @jali-ai Changed that, but that doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 31):

All static asset files/directories need to be listed in the `angular-cli.json` file.

## Adding assets

To add your assets you can either:

- Put your image file in the default `assets` folder (which is already listed in the `angular-cli.json` file.
- Or add a new directory inside of `app/` (e.g. in your case you could use `app/images`, and then reference that in `angular-cli.json`)

angular-cli.json:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "images"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

## Referencing files

Like @jali-ai mentioned in the comments `background-url` should be `background-image` and you can refer to your asset like this:

```
.image {
   background-image: url('images/image.png'); 
}
```

Here is an example of the [angular-cli.json file](https://github.com/adriancarriger/udacity-transportation/blob/master/angular-cli.json#L11) and a [reference](https://github.com/adriancarriger/udacity-transportation/blob/master/src/app/home/home.component.scss#L5) to an asset

Comment: Are you implicitly saying that the OP's intent isn't possible? i.e. having the image 'local' to the component?

I was able to accomplish it using SystemJS as the bundler.

Is this perhaps considered incorrect Angular2 component composition?

Comment: I've been using webpack and have not found a full solution to this, which makes it more difficult to create reusable components. You can inline SVGs in your css, but I usually just put everything in an assets folder. Here's a related issue: [#6637](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6637)

Comment: If you like to have assets with you module directory it selves, you can add your assets folders pattern something like '*\**/images/**.png'

Comment: i tried the same with 'less', but it is not working.

Comment: The assets list has nothing to do with resolving files. It is for directly copying files over when you build. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md Your background image link worked because your images folder is inside of your app root (src)

Comment: Agree with UserX. You need to restart the app. It will work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be still an issue with angular-CLI and webpack (using 1.0.3).

If you add the asset folder to the `angular-cli.json` and define the path relatively, the build still fails, not finding the ressources `url('someRelativeLink')`.

I used a work around and put all CSS definitions in:

```
@Component({
  styles: [...]
})
```

Instead of a `styleUrls` file.

After doinig that everything was fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use caret syntax to ignore url processing

```
background-image: url('^images/objects/loader.png');
```

Angular CLI just passthrough your url removing Caret

```
background-image: url('images/objects/loader.png');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.image {
    background-image: url('./assets/images/image.png'); 
}
```