# How to couple images with a module?

Tags: css, image, path, angular-cli

This is related to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40747680)

We have a masthead component in Angular 1.6 that I am porting to Angular2 in a project using the Angular CLI. In Angular 1.6 it was simple to have an image alongside your controller and its CSS, and then easily reference it with a path relative to the component directory. For example:

```
-components
--my-component
---my-component.controller.js
---my-component.css
---my-image.jpg

In my-component.css:
 background-image: url(my-image.jpg);
```

According to the referenced question, this isn't possible with the Angular CLI. They recommend moving the image to an assets folder. Not an ideal solution, but okay. Surely if I split this component into its own node_module and import from there, Angular will be smart enough to allow paths relative to the node_module, right? So far, no luck there either.

So how are we expected to use node_modules that contain images specific to that module? The obvious work-around for us now is to add a postinstall script that copies the image from the module to the dependent project's assets folder - but that seems hacky and requires us to assume they have a particular asset folder setup.

In summary:

- Is there some way to reference images that are located in a component folder relative to that folder?
- If not, is there some way to reference images that are located in a node_module relative to the `node_module`?
- If not, what's the best way to setup and maintain a module coupled with its images? Is postinstall the best idea for a work-around?

This one's racking my brain and it's the first time I've really questioned Angular2 and the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

The [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) is going to cede control of image rendering to [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), based on the settings that webpack includes by default. You can change the default settings by ejecting webpack from the Angular CLI by executing the [ng-eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) command. Once you have done this, you can reference your images in the webpack.config.js file.