# Background image not found after deploying angular 4 app into tomcat

Tags: angular, tomcat, webpack, angular-cli

I am working on angular app and I have generated project structure with angular-cli.
I am using below css in on of my component :

```
.profilePic{
    height:67px;
    width: 67px;
    display: block;
    background: url('/assets/images/header-profile-pic.png') no-repeat center center
}
```

[image: Folder structure]

When I do `ng serve` for dev purpose ; app runs fine on localhost:4200 and can able to load above image.

When I do `ng build --prod` , it generates `dist` folder, then I copy this dist folder to my deployment server(tomcat in my case) and when try to open application, background image doesn't load.

On console it shows 404 error.

I have set base tag in my HTML `<base href="./">`.
In dist folder, assets folder is at root level. If i try to update css to path like `background: url('./assets/images/header-profile-pic.png') no-repeat center center`; ng-build gives me an error,

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/images/header-profile-pic.png' in 'D:\Node\Angular 2\Router\src\app\login-component'`

I have tried [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748755/1608841) second bullet point and it does work. But I want to put my all images in assets folder only.

Is there any way that background image will be available in both my Dev as well as Prod env.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

As <`image`> tag accepts the source path, try this workaround:

Set the style online in the HTML:

```
...[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(/assets/images/header-profile-pic.png)'}" ..
```

and leave in the CSS:

```
background: no-repeat center center;
```

---

Old answer:

You don't have to change your stylesheet for development and production.
Correct it to the following:

```
background: url(/assets/images/header-profile-pic.png) no-repeat center center
```

Answer (score 0):

try this I'm not sure about it

remove backslash before the assets

```
background: url('assets/images/header-profile-pic.png') no-repeat center center;
```